# spread operator vs immutable.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

It seems like when using redux with react, immutable.js has become almost a industry standard.
My question is, aren't we making changes to our redux states immutably when we are using the spread operator? For example,

```
const reducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case actionType.SOME_ACTION:
            return {
                ...state,
                someState: state.someState.filter(etc=>etc)
            }
    }
```

Isn't the way I am setting the state with redux immutable? What is the benefit of using immutable.js OVER spread operator way of making objects immutable?

Apologies if this question has been asked, but I couldn't find the answer that satisfied me. I understand the benefits of immutable objects, but not the importance of using the immutable.js library over the dot operator.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Short Answer

Yes! The ES6 spread operator can be used as a replacement for immutable.js entirely, but there is one major caveat, you must maintain situational awareness at all times.

## VERY Long Answer

You, and your fellow developers, will be 100% responsible for maintaining immutability, rather than letting immutable.js take care of it for you. Here's a breakdown of how you can manage an immutable state all by yourself using the ES6 'spread operator', and its various functions like `filter` and `map`.

The following will explore removing and adding values to an array or object in an immutable and mutated way. I log out the `initialState` and `newState` in each example to demonstrate if we've mutated `initialState`. The reason this is important, is because Redux will not instruct the UI to re-render if the `initialState` and `newState` are exactly the same.

**Note:** Immutable.js would crash the application if you tried any of the mutated solutions below.

### Remove element from Array

#### Immutable way

```js
const initialState = {
  members: ['Pete', 'Paul', 'George', 'John']
}
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
case 'REMOVE_MEMBER':
  return {
    ...state,
    members: state.members.filter(
      member => member !== action.member
    )
  }
  }
}
const newState = reducer(
  initialState,
  {type: 'REMOVE_MEMBER', member: 'Pete'}
);

console.log('initialState', initialState);
console.log('newState', newState);
```

#### Mutated way

```js
const initialState = {
  members: ['Pete', 'Paul', 'George', 'John']
}
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
case 'REMOVE_MEMBER':
  state.members.forEach((member, i) => {
    if (member === action.member) {
      state.members.splice(i, 1)
    }
  })
  return {
    ...state,
    members: state.members
  }
  }
}
const newState = reducer(
  initialState,
  {type: 'REMOVE_MEMBER', member: 'Pete'}
);

console.log('initialState', initialState);
console.log('newState', newState);
```

### Add element to Array

#### Immutable way

```js
const initialState = {
  members: ['Paul', 'George', 'John']
}
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
case 'ADD_MEMBER':
  return {
    ...state,
    members: [...state.members, action.member]
  }
  }
}
const newState = reducer(
  initialState,
  {type: 'ADD_MEMBER', member: 'Ringo'}
);

console.log('initialState', initialState);
console.log('newState', newState);
```

#### Mutated way

```js
const initialState = {
  members: ['Paul', 'George', 'John']
}
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
case 'ADD_MEMBER':
  state.members.push(action.member);
  return {
    ...state,
    members: state.members
  }
  }
}
const newState = reducer(
  initialState,
  {type: 'ADD_MEMBER', member: 'Ringo'}
);

console.log('initialState', initialState);
console.log('newState', newState);
```

### Update Array

#### Immutable way

```js
const initialState = {
  members: ['Paul', 'Pete', 'George', 'John']
}
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
case 'UPDATE_MEMBER':
  return {
    ...state,
    members: state.members.map(member => member === action.member ? action.replacement : member)
  }
  }
}
const newState = reducer(
  initialState,
  {type: 'UPDATE_MEMBER', member: 'Pete', replacement: 'Ringo'}
);

console.log('initialState', initialState);
console.log('newState', newState);
```

#### Mutated way

```js
const initialState = {
  members: ['Paul', 'Pete', 'George', 'John']
}
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
case 'UPDATE_MEMBER':
  state.members.forEach((member, i) => {
    if (member === action.member) {
      state.members[i] = action.replacement;
    }
  })
  return {
    ...state,
    members: state.members
  }
  }
}
const newState = reducer(
  initialState,
  {type: 'UPDATE_MEMBER', member: 'Pete', replacement: 'Ringo'}
);

console.log('initialState', initialState);
console.log('newState', newState);
```

### Merge Arrays

#### Immutable way

```js
const initialState = {
  members: ['Paul', 'Ringo']
}
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
case 'MERGE_MEMBERS':
  return {
    ...state,
    members: [...state.members, ...action.members]
  }
  }
}
const newState = reducer(
  initialState,
  {type: 'MERGE_MEMBERS', members: ['George', 'John']}
);

console.log('initialState', initialState);
console.log('newState', newState);
```

#### Mutated way

```js
const initialState = {
  members: ['Paul', 'Ringo']
}
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
case 'MERGE_MEMBERS':
  action.members.forEach(member => state.members.push(member))
  return {
    ...state,
    members: state.members
  }
  }
}
const newState = reducer(
  initialState,
  {type: 'MERGE_MEMBERS', members: ['George', 'John']}
);

console.log('initialState', initialState);
console.log('newState', newState);
```

The above examples of mutating an array may seem like obvious bad practices to a seasoned developer, but an easy pitfall for someone new on the scene. We'd hope that any of the **Mutated way** code snippets would get caught in code review, but that's not always the case.
Let's talk a little bit about objects, which are more cumbersome when handling immutability on your own.

### Remove from Object

#### Immutable way

```js
const initialState = {
  members: {
paul: {
  name: 'Paul',
  instrument: 'Guitar'
},
stuart: {
  name: 'Stuart',
  instrument: 'Bass'
}
  }
}
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
case 'REMOVE_MEMBER':
  let { [action.member]: _, ...members } = state.members
  return {
    ...state,
    members
  }
  }
}
const newState = reducer(
  initialState,
  {type: 'REMOVE_MEMBER', member: 'stuart'}
);

console.log('initialState', initialState);
console.log('newState', newState);
```

#### Mutated way

```js
const initialState = {
  members: {
paul: {
  name: 'Paul',
  instrument: 'Guitar'
},
stuart: {
  name: 'Stuart',
  instrument: 'Bass'
}
  }
}
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
case 'REMOVE_MEMBER':
  delete state.members[action.member]
  return {
    ...state,
    members: state.members
  }
  }
}
const newState = reducer(
  initialState,
  {type: 'REMOVE_MEMBER', member: 'stuart'}
);

console.log('initialState', initialState);
console.log('newState', newState);
```

### Update Object

#### Immutable way

```js
const initialState = {
  members: {
paul: {
  name: 'Paul',
  instrument: 'Guitar'
},
ringo: {
  name: 'George',
  instrument: 'Guitar'
}
  }
}
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
case 'CHANGE_INSTRUMENT':
  return {
    ...state,
    members: {
      ...state.members,
      [action.key]: {
        ...state.members[action.member],
        instrument: action.instrument
      }
    }
  }
  }
}
const newState = reducer(
  initialState,
  {type: 'CHANGE_INSTRUMENT', member: 'paul', instrument: 'Bass'}
);

console.log('initialState', initialState);
console.log('newState', newState);
```

#### Mutated way

```js
const initialState = {
  members: {
paul: {
  name: 'Paul',
  instrument: 'Guitar'
},
ringo: {
  name: 'George',
  instrument: 'Guitar'
}
  }
}
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
case 'CHANGE_INSTRUMENT':
  state.members[action.member].instrument = action.instrument
  return {
    ...state,
    members: state.members
  }
  }
}
const newState = reducer(
  initialState,
  {type: 'CHANGE_INSTRUMENT', member: 'paul', instrument: 'Bass'}
);

console.log('initialState', initialState);
console.log('newState', newState);
```

If you've made it down this far, congratulations! I know this has been a long winded post, but I felt it was important to demonstrate all the **Mutated ways** that you'll need to prevent yourself without Immutable.js. One huge advantage to using Immutable.js, beyond preventing you from writing bad code, is the helper methods, like `mergeDeep` and `updateIn`

### Immutable.JS

#### mergeDeep

```js
const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({
  members: {
    paul: {
      name: 'Paul',
      instrument: 'Guitar'
    },
    ringo: {
      name: 'George',
      instrument: 'Guitar'
    }
  }
})
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_MEMBERS':
      return state.mergeDeep({members: action.members})
  }
}
const newState = reducer(
  initialState,
  {
    type: 'ADD_MEMBERS',
    members: {
      george: { name: 'George', instrument: 'Guitar' },
      john: { name: 'John', instrument: 'Guitar' }
    }
  }
);

console.log('initialState', initialState);
console.log('newState', newState);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.min.js"></script>
```

#### updateIn

```js
const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({
  members: {
    paul: {
      name: 'Paul',
      instrument: 'Guitar'
    },
    ringo: {
      name: 'George',
      instrument: 'Guitar'
    }
  }
})
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'CHANGE_INSTRUMENT':
      return state.updateIn(['members', action.member, 'instrument'], instrument => action.instrument)
  }
}
const newState = reducer(
  initialState,
  {type: 'CHANGE_INSTRUMENT', member: 'paul', instrument: 'Bass'}
);

console.log('initialState', initialState);
console.log('newState', newState);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, but isnt the spread syntax achieving what immutable.js is trying to achieve? I am confused why immutable.js has so much hype and support behind it, when something similar can be achieved with the spread operator

Comment: @YoungMoon, check out my updated answer with a detailed breakdown of how you can use pure ES6 to achieve immutability.

Comment: Forgot to thank you for the most amazing answer. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> Isn't the way I am setting the state with Redux immutable?

In your example code (assuming the real function passed to `filter` doesn’t do any mutation), yes.

> What is the benefit of using immutable.js OVER spread operator way of making objects immutable?

Two major reasons:

1. It’s not (easily) possible to accidentally mutate an Immutable collection object, as the public API does not permit it. Whereas with built-in JS collections, it is. Deep-freezing (recursively calling [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)) can help this a bit.
2. Efficient* use of immutable updates with built-in collections can be challenging. Immutable.js uses [tries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) internally to make updates more efficient than is possible with vanilla-usage of native collections.

If you want to use built-in collections, consider using [Immer](https://github.com/mweststrate/immer), which gives a nicer API for immutable updates while also freezing the objects it creates, helping mitigate the first issue (but not the second).

<sub>* Efficient meaning time complexity of e.g. object construction and GC runs due to increased object churn.</sub>